# Cauchy-Schwarz Inside Integral Sign

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was reading a paper when I came across this:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1g(x+sp)^Tp\cdot ds&\ \leq \int_0^1\|g(x+sp)\|\cdot \|p\|\cdot ds
\end{align}

where $x,p\in \mathbb R^n$ and $g:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$.

I follow that $$a^Tb\leq \|a\| \|b\|$$

Because of Cauchy-Schwarz but I am not sure why this can be done *inside* the integral sign. Are there any regularity conditions on $g$ for which this can be done?

Comment: Surely if $a<b$, then $a<b$ underneath integral signs, too.

Comment: @Arkamis but $s$ is _inside_ g (i.e. it is an argument of g). Does that matter? Would the statement be true if $g$ were discontinuous?

Comment: Think about it like this: On $x > 0$, then $f(x) \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} 2x^2 > x^2 \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} g(x)$. Surely, $f(x) > g(x)$ underneath any integral over $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}_+$, no?

Comment: @Arkamis, that makes sense. The area interpretation of integral took it away. Thanks! If you post your comment as an answer, I'd love to accept it and close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely if $a<b$, then $a<b$ underneath integral signs, too.